Bayes Credible set for Gamma distribution
Given iid observations of x that follows $beta(\theta, 1)$ pdf and we assume $\theta$ has a $gamma(r,\lambda)$ prior pdf.
The likelihood function of the beta is given as
$$L(\theta|x_i) = \theta^n e^{-\sum log x_i} e^{\theta \sum log x_i}$$
and the prior pdf as
$$f(\theta) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(r)\lambda^r}\theta^{r-1}e^{-\frac{\theta}{\lambda}}$$
By finding the posterior distribution of a beta pdf and gamma prior, we would get a gamma distribution with shape parameter $r+n$ and scale parameter $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\lambda}-\sum log x_i} = \lambda - (\sum log x_i)^{-1}$
Now we are to find a $1-\alpha$ Bayes credible set for $\theta$. I tried using the CDF of a gamma distribution which is given as $$F(x, r', \lambda') = \frac{\gamma(r', \lambda' x)}{\Gamma(r')}$$. Using the CDF will result in finding the interval such that
solving equation 1 and 2 will result in finding the Bayes credible set
$$F(a, r', \lambda') = \frac{\alpha}{2}...eqn(1)$$ and $$F(b, r', \lambda') = 1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}...eqn(2)$$ where $r'$ and $\lambda'$ are the parameters of the posterior distribution of the gamma distribution.
I don't know if I am right or not. Can someone help me expand it if I am not all that right or help expand it to find the Bayes credible set.
